# Pass data to another scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is what I have:

```
$http.get("http://localhost/app/api/Suppliers").success(function(response) {
    $scope.dataSource = response;
    console.log($scope.dataSource);
    $scope.safeApply(function() {
        $scope.settings.columns[3] = $scope.dataSource;
    });
}); 


$scope.settings  = {
    colHeaders: ["Code", "Comments"],
    contextMenu : ["row_above","row_below","remove_row"],
    colWidths: [100, 100],
    columns : [
        {   type: 'dropdown',
            source: ['Not Started', 'In Progress', 'Completed']
        },
        {},
        {},
        {   type: 'dropdown',
            source: $scope.dataSource,
        }
    ]
};
```

Problem is `$scope.dataSource` is undefined, it's not displaying the data. What should be the solution to this?

UPDATE:
This displays the data in my $http call. But in the settings source when I call source: **$scope.dataSource** is undefined

Comment: try this  $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.settings.columns.slice(3,0, $scope.dataSource);
    });

Comment: @Joy response is okay. So I think the problem is with the $scope.dataSource

Comment: @SSH still to no avail :(

Comment: @Joy when I hardcoded an array, it's working fine but with data from json it's not working

Comment: @Joy as I said, in the console, it's undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108917/discussion-between-betty-barnes-and-joy).

Comment: and remove that safeApply which should not exist, and especially in a $http call where the scope is digested for you

Comment: Yes I have removed it but it's undefined still

Comment: @floribon can you help?

Comment: use $broadcast & $on to broadcast it to another scope?

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes I don't really understand your problem. Where is `$scope.dataSource` being undefined? In your `console.log`? Try to replace `.success` by `.then`

Comment: @floribon it's working inside the $http but in $scope.settings source it's undefined

Comment: @MrNew sorry I don't understand. But what I need is to have a global variable to store the value of the data from $http. And access it in source.

Answer (score 0):

When you are making a request to the server, the rest of the controller will be compiled then you will enter the success function

you are declaring your array inside the `success` of your request, it's better be declared outside like this

```
$scope.dataSource = []

$http.get("http://localhost/app/api/Suppliers").success(function(response) {
    $scope.dataSource = response;
    console.log($scope.dataSource);
    $scope.safeApply(function() {
        $scope.settings.columns[3] = $scope.dataSource;
    });
});
```

UPDATE

try this

```
$http.get("http://localhost/app/api/Suppliers").success(function(response) {
      $scope.dataSource = response;
      console.log($scope.dataSource);

      getSetting();

      $scope.safeApply(function() {
        $scope.settings.columns[3] = $scope.dataSource;
      });
    });


    var getSetting = function() {
      $scope.settings = {
        colHeaders: ["Code", "Comments"],
        contextMenu: ["row_above", "row_below", "remove_row"],
        colWidths: [100, 100],
        columns: [{
          type: 'dropdown',
          source: ['Not Started', 'In Progress', 'Completed']
        }, {}, {}, {
          type: 'dropdown',
          source: $scope.dataSource,
        }]
      };
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for this. But I've already tried this one. But the array contains 0.

Comment: still not working bro. I think I need an array variable to put the values of $scope.dataSource.

Comment: `source: $scope.dataSource,` there is an extra comma, I know it's not the issue but just to make sure, good luck

Answer (score 0):

So first you need to be aware that when you declare `$scope.settings = {...}` the `$http` call will not be over yet, so instead of writting

```
{
  type: 'dropdown',
  source: $scope.dataSource,
}
```

You may as well simply write

```
{
  type: 'dropdown',
  source: null,
}
```

Then when the `$http` call finishes, I assume you want to set this `source` property. However in your code you are overriding the whole `$scope.settings.columns[3]` instead of just its `source` property.

Try this instead:

```
$http.get("http://localhost/app/api/Suppliers").success(function(response) {
  $scope.dataSource = response;
  console.log($scope.dataSource);
  $scope.settings.columns[3].source = $scope.dataSource;
});
```

Note that I have removed the `safeApply` which is an anti-pattern. Here the `$http` call will take care of the digest cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

```
$scope.suppliers = [];

$http.get("http://localhost/i95/api/Suppliers").success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $scope.suppliers.push(data[i].company);
    }
    console.log($scope.suppliers);
});
```

So creating a global variable and adding push method fixed the issue.